# How to change default timeout of Http Client in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http

In Laravel default timeout for Http Client requests is 30 seconds. But I want to change it to 5 seconds. I already know that it is possible by calling `timeout(5)` function on Http (PendingRequest) instance:

```
Http::timeout(5)->get('www.example.com');
```

But I don't want to call it each time I access Http facade. I want it to be its default behaviour. What I tried so far:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Factory;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

public function register()

    $this->app->bind(Factory::class, static fn () => (new Factory)->withOptions(['timeout' => 5]));
}
```

It was doing what I need but I got faced a problem when I call Http client more than one time in one API request.

For example I have an API to upload document and then generate contract number for that to store in database:

```
$response1 = Http::baseUrl('www.storageservice.com')->attach('document', 'file_contents', 'document.pdf')->post('/upload');
$response2 = Http::baseUrl('www.numbergenerator.com')
// ->post('/generate/number');
```

If I debug `$response2` I can see the `document` file attached to its body. Which means I am using exact same Http instance with first API call for second one.

That happens just because the code I have written in `AppServiceProvider`.
When I delete the line in `AppServiceProvider` everything works well again but default timeout is still 30 seconds.

I know that for each `Http` call I can call `new()` method to create new instance of it like:

```
$response1 = Http::new()->baseUrl('www.storageservice.com')->attach('document', 'file_contents', 'document.pdf')->post('/upload');
$response2 = Http::new()->baseUrl('www.numbergenerator.com')
// ->post('/generate/number');
```

but it seems reverse engineering a bit. If I need to call a function each time so it would be `timeout` surely.

Any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem creating new Class that extends `Factory` class and binding them.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Factory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

public function boot(): void
{
    $this->app->bind(Factory::class, function ($app) {
        return new MyCustomHttpClientFactory($app->make(Dispatcher::class));
    });
}
```

`MyCustomHttpClientFactory`:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Factory;

class MyCustomHttpClientFactory extends Factory
{
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (static::hasMacro($method)) {
            return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
        }

        return tap($this->newPendingRequest(), function ($request) {
            $request
                //This line has changed from the base factory class
                ->withOptions(['timeout' => 5]);
        })->{$method}(...$parameters);
    }
}
```

Whenever `Factory` class get needed by app new instance of `MyCustomHttpClientFactory`  will be used. And in `MyCustomHttpClientFactory` I am looking for any method call then catch `$this->newPendingRequest()` by `tap` function then attach `withOptions` method to it.

Btw timeout set in `__constructor` of `PendingRequest` class:

```
public function __construct(Factory $factory = null)
{
    $this->factory = $factory;
    $this->middleware = new Collection;
    $this->asJson();
    $this->options = [
        'connect_timeout' => 10,
        'http_errors' => false,
        'timeout' => 30,
    ];
    $this->beforeSendingCallbacks = collect([function (Request $request, array $options, PendingRequest $pendingRequest) {
        $pendingRequest->request = $request;
        $pendingRequest->cookies = $options['cookies'];
        $pendingRequest->dispatchRequestSendingEvent();
    }]);
}
```